# A product of a $H^1_0(\Omega)$ function with a function defined on $S^{N-1}$ is also in $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, linear-pde, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega = B_1(0)$ the ball centered at $0$ with radius equal 1 and $u \in H^1_0(\Omega).$ Also consider $f \in C^\infty(S^{N-1})$. I'm trying to prove the function $g(x) := u(x) f(x/|x|)$ is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. The difficulties for me are in the fact that $x/|x|$ has no weak derivative. I took a sequence $u_n \in C^1_0(\Omega)$ such that
$$||u_n - u||_{H^1(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0.$$
My first attempt was to prove that $g_n(x) := u_n(x) f(x/|x|)$ is in $C^1_0(\Omega)$. I don't think this is true.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: For $n\geq2$, you can use that $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $f'\in L_{loc}^{\frac{n}{2}-\varepsilon}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ to get that the usual product rule applies.

Comment: Thank you Jose.

Comment: When $n=1$, it is false, just take $f(x) = x$ (that is $f(1) = 1$ and $f(-1) = -1$) and $u(0)\neq 0$. Then $u(x) \,f(x/|x|) = u(x) \,\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ is discontinuous and so not in $H^1_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is true for $n = 2$. Let us identify $f$ with a function on $[0,2\pi]$. Suppose that $u \equiv 1$ on a small ball with radius $R$ around the origin. Then, we get
$$
|\nabla g(x)| = \frac1{r(x)} |f'(\theta(x))|
$$
for $0 < |x| < R$
with the usual polar coordinates $(r(x), \theta(x))$.
That is, $g$ is differentiable on $B_R \setminus \{0\}$. However,
$$
\int_{B_R} |\nabla g(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x
=
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R \frac1{r^2} |f'(\theta)|^2 r \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta
=
\int_0^{2\pi}|f'(\theta)|^2 \mathrm{d}\theta
\int_0^R \frac1{r}\mathrm{d}r
$$
and this is $+\infty$ (unless $f$ is constant).

Comment: Thank you gerw for your reply. That makes sense.